# How to get count of documents that would be added if one selects another aggregation options of an array-field in elastic search

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Let's say we have four documents with a `tags` field. It can contain multiple strings, let's say `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

```
docA.tags = ['foo']
docB.tags = ['bar']
docC.tags = ['foo', 'bar']
docD.tags = ['foo', 'baz']
```

I query the docs using aggregations so I get the four documents and a list of three buckets with the count that matches the specific tag.

```
buckets = [
  {key: 'bar', doc_count: 2}, // docB, docC
  {key: 'foo', doc_count: 3}, // docA, docC, docD
  {key: 'baz', doc_count: 1}  // docD
]
```

If I now run another query and add one of those tags – lets say `foo` – as a terms-filter to the query, I only get the docs (`docA`, `docC`, `docD`) that have this tag. That's what I want.

But I also get another list of possible aggregations with updated counts.

```
buckets = [
  {key: 'bar', doc_count: 1}, // docC
  {key: 'baz', doc_count: 1}, // docD
]
```

But these counts don't really match what's happening. They reflect the count of documents that match both of the tags, the one I selected in the first place (`foo`) AND the one of the bucket (`bar` or `baz`).

But if I then select a second tag – let's say `baz` – I get documents that have been tagged with `foo` OR `baz`. That's because I use the `terms` filter.

So what I really want is this

```
buckets = [
  {key: 'bar', doc_count: 1}, //docB
  {key: 'baz', doc_count: 0},
]
```

How can I achieve that the counts are appropriate. They should reflect the count of documents that would be added if I select the second tag. An example of this is [here](http://lnavigation.demo.aheadworks.com/index.php/electronics-computers.html?color=70).

I already tried to use `post_filter` but that always gives me the first result. Than a `min_doc_count`-flag to the aggs, but this only shows me the combinations that would result in `count=0`.

I have a solution for this, but it seem pretty complicated to me. For this I would have to run another request for each aggregation where I invert the filter criteria. So in the upper example I have to make a query to all docs that don't have the tag foo and match the rest of the query. The aggregation results would be exactly what I needed.

Comment: Have you tried mapping your `tags` field as `nested` type and using nested query and aggregation?

Comment: Thanks for fixing :)
no, but I have seen this. In real use case I have 5 aggregations with terms. Do you think it might be worth looking more deeply into nested aggregations?

Comment: Yes, feel free to have a look and see if it solves your problem. If not, get back here and we'll find a solution ;-)

Comment: Maybe I got this wrong but the docs suggest that this only works for nested documents. As I pointed out I have multiple parallel terms which can be filtered. Do you have a suggestion how to solve the problem using nested aggregations?

Comment: Yes, you'd need the `tags` field to be of `nested` type for this to work and then you'll be able to match on the exact tags without others being selected. If I'm not mistaken, you're more or less experiencing [the problem described here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html).

Comment: Sadly not. Can't get my head around this. Also I already solved this be making additional requests just for the counts. It's a solution I can live with currently. Thanks again for you suggestions.

Comment: Could you try asking in simpler terms? Maybe step-by-step explanation using example pages or like "If I choose this, I should see these docs and aggregations in the page" etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do something a little atypical for facets/aggregations.

(However, it's not invalid... it makes a lot of sense to understand how the size of your selection will change through the application of a filter)

What I think you're asking for is:

1. Display results for: *QUERY* **AND** *FILTER*
2. Display term aggregation counts for:  *QUERY* **NOT** *FILTER*

[image]

You mentioned you're doing subsequent request(s) for counts?  You should be able to construct this aggregation request inside your main search request.

Structurally it's:

- match: (**QUERY**) or match_all
- aggregations:

  - [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html): { not: (**FILTER**) }

    - aggregations: { terms: ... }
- [post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html): (**FILTER**)

That *post_filter* is executed after the aggregations are calculated (but still applied to the search results) so your results will be what you expect.

The aggregations are working in the scope of *the search query alone*.  (The postfilter has not been applied yet.)

The [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) excludes all documents matching **FILTER** from the search query results before the Terms Aggregation calculates the counts.

(giving you the left outside edge of the Venn shown above, but just for the counts)

Comment: that sounds perfectly reasonable. Will try that later. Thanks for this detailed answer. Will get back report id that works

Comment: Seems not to work, since the documents are filtered by the aggregation filter and can't be readded to the result by the post filter. Or am I doing something wrong here:

{ body: { query: { filtered: { filter: { bool: { must_not: [ { terms: { tags: [ 'foo' ] } } ] } } } }, post_filter: { bool: { must: [ { terms: { subjects: [ 'foo' ] } } ] } } }

Comment: My suggestion was not to use a filtered query.  Just a `match` or `match_all` as needed.  (The post_filter can do equivalent filtering for you).    Then use a `filter` aggregation to define your NOT condition.  (Which you'd then nest your `terms` aggregation inside of).... I think I got the initial order wrong, editing answer.